# Error in Ansible installation on Linux machine

Tags: linux, unix, ansible

I am trying to install ansible in Linux machine. while executing the below command getting the errors:

```
sudo yum install ansible -y
```

The errors:

```
**Last metadata expiration check: 0:11:35 ago on Thu 23 Jul 2020 03:29:27 AM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python-jinja2 needed by ansible-2.9.10-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides PyYAML needed by ansible-2.9.10-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-setuptools needed by ansible-2.9.10-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-six needed by ansible-2.9.10-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python2-cryptography needed by ansible-2.9.10-1.el7.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)**
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your package repositories. But fixing that is not a Stack Overflow topic.

Comment: Please install below package `yum install http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
`

Comment: I  installed above epel release but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an installation issue possibly OS has not come fully bundled with all python packages if it was a custom OS image. Suggest installing the required packages using yum and rerunning sudo yum install ansible -y

If you have python3-pip installed python3-dev installed you can run
`sudo pip3 install ansible`

Comment: Above suggestion worked.Thanks a lot for the help and support.